# Cannot open include file: except.h

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sdk

EDIT: Solved thanks to Hans Passant, much appreciated! :)

My Win32 app will not compile due to the following error:

```
  Error 1: error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h'
```

I am using VS Express for Desktop and I have manually installed the Windows 7 SDK. The SDK path, `C:\Program Files x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0` in my case, is included under Additional Include Directories, Include Directories and Additional Libary Directories with the appropriate include/lib suffixes.

Based on what I can tell excpt.h is where it's supposed to be - I was able to access it via the windows.h header.  I even re-installed VS, but I still can't run the program.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656856/cant-get-visual-studio-c-include-file-excpt-h-to-get-installed) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vcgeneral/thread/df97a541-c630-4797-b6a0-baf768b733bb).

Comment: There is no "excpt.h" in the SDK's include directory.  It is in your compiler's include directory, vc/include.  Hard to reverse-engineer how you messed up the config.  Using an old version of the SDK may well be part of the problem.