# Dart native extension demo “sample_extension” on VS2010 setup

Tags: dart, dart-native-extension

I've been able to create/compile the simple_extension.dll (32bit) only on PC's with VS2010 C++ Express Edition. I'm following [WHesse's article](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/native-extensions-for-standalone-dart-vm/) on native extensions section [Building on Windows](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/native-extensions-for-standalone-dart-vm/#building-on-windows). My PC  on the other hand has Windows 2008 Server R2 64bit, VS2010 Ultimate, and Dart 64bit (SDK version 1.5.0-dev.4.17).

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

in http://dart.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dart/samples/sample_extension/sample_extension.cc are not found.

Just guessing but I don't think the article's build steps are intended for full version VS2010 C++ projects or maybe 64bit?

Does anyone have a VS2010 C++ (full version) solution file working for sample_extension project?

Update: Output from running example_build.dart

```
Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:1283
Building project "C:\Users\OSSDevYorgi\DartPlayground\ccompile-master\example\../example/sample_extension.yaml"
sample_extension_dllmain_win.cc

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\windows.h(151) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h': No such file or directory

sample_extension.cc

sample_extension.cc(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'string.h': No such file or directory

Generating Code...

Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

sample_extension_dllmain_win.cc

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\windows.h(151) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h': No such file or directory

sample_extension.cc

sample_extension.cc(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'string.h': No such file or directory

Generating Code...

Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Building complete with some errors
```

Comment: Try this package for experimenting. If something will not work I can try to help you. http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/ccompilers

Comment: @mezoni: Thanks for your help. Updating post with sample_extension output

Comment: Please read at least first this about problem with `excpt.h`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656856/cant-get-visual-studio-c-include-file-excpt-h-to-get-installed