# Set VC++ command line messages language

Tags: visual-c++-2010

MS VC++ compiler produces error and warning messages on local language. How to change VC++ command line warning and error messages language to English?

Comment: Reading your name I would assume you're from Russia (just joking) ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed MS VS 2010 Russian (strange, because previously I was unable because of error during uninstall), now all messages are in English which is good. Think this is the only solution here.

Comment: Then need to remove all VS 2010 components and reinstall because of building errors. Solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13665990/630169