# VS does not see the standard include files

Tags: c, visual-studio, driver

Even the code as simple as -

```
#include <ntdef.h>
#include <wdf.h>

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Is giving more than 200 errors. All of them are like: "Cannot open source file smth.h" Error screenshot - https://prnt.sc/z7dnm1
One more screenshot - https://prnt.sc/z7dpfi

I am using the latest visual studio 2019. Have tried repair already

Project is empty KDMF driver(Windows kernel mode driver)

EDIT 1:
Searchable error text:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "excpt.h"   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ntdef.h  2160    
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "string.h"  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared\guiddef.h    146 
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "ctype.h"   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ntdef.h  24  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "wdmsec.h"  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    486 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "wchar_t" is undefined   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ntdef.h  529 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ntdef.h  2165    
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfcommonbuffer.h  223 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfcommonbuffer.h  233 
Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfcore.h  118 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DEVICE_RELATION_TYPE" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    999 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PIRP" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    1615    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PIRP" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    1637    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POHANDLE" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    1670    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POHANDLE" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    1684    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PDEVICE_OBJECT" is undefined    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    1983    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PDEVICE_OBJECT" is undefined    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    1991    
Error (active)  E0079   expected a type specifier   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    2004    
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    2006    
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    2014    
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    2029    
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    2039    
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    2054    
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    2064    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PIRP" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    2086    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PIRP" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    2097    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PIRP" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    2117    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PIRP" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    2130    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PIRP" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    2152    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PIRP" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    2167    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "ACCESS_MASK" is undefined   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    2587    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "ACCESS_MASK" is undefined   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    2604    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "ACCESS_MASK" is undefined   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    2630    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "ACCESS_MASK" is undefined   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    2647    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DEVICE_TYPE" is undefined   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    3173    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DEVICE_TYPE" is undefined   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    3183    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DEVICE_REGISTRY_PROPERTY" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    3698    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DEVICE_REGISTRY_PROPERTY" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    3715    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DEVICE_REGISTRY_PROPERTY" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    3741    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POOL_TYPE" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    3744    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DEVICE_REGISTRY_PROPERTY" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    3759    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POOL_TYPE" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    3762    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PPNP_BUS_INFORMATION" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    3843    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PPNP_BUS_INFORMATION" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    3853    
Error (active)  E0079   expected a type specifier   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    4231    
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    4233    
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    4241    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POOL_TYPE" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    4412    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POOL_TYPE" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdevice.h    4432    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmaenabler.h    221 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DMA_WIDTH" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmaenabler.h    276 
Error (active)  E0079   expected a type specifier   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmaenabler.h    369 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmaenabler.h    371 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmaenabler.h    379 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmaenabler.h    394 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmaenabler.h    404 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmaenabler.h    450 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmaenabler.h    462 
Error (active)  E0079   expected a type specifier   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmaenabler.h    479 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmaenabler.h    481 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmaenabler.h    491 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PSCATTER_GATHER_LIST" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmatransaction.h    69  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PMDL" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmatransaction.h    87  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DMA_COMPLETION_STATUS" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmatransaction.h    111 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PMDL" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmatransaction.h    183 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PMDL" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmatransaction.h    203 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PMDL" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmatransaction.h    232 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PMDL" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmatransaction.h    252 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmatransaction.h    462 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmatransaction.h    472 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmatransaction.h    541 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdmatransaction.h    551 
Error (active)  E0079   expected a type specifier   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdpc.h   217 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdpc.h   219 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdpc.h   227 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PDRIVER_OBJECT" is undefined    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdriver.h    210 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PDRIVER_OBJECT" is undefined    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdriver.h    227 
Error (active)  E0079   expected a type specifier   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdriver.h    273 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdriver.h    275 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdriver.h    283 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "ACCESS_MASK" is undefined   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdriver.h    305 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "ACCESS_MASK" is undefined   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfdriver.h    320 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdffdo.h   115 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdffdo.h   125 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "ACCESS_MASK" is undefined   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdffdo.h   149 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "ACCESS_MASK" is undefined   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdffdo.h   166 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DEVICE_REGISTRY_PROPERTY" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdffdo.h   190 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DEVICE_REGISTRY_PROPERTY" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdffdo.h   207 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DEVICE_REGISTRY_PROPERTY" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdffdo.h   233 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POOL_TYPE" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdffdo.h   236 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DEVICE_REGISTRY_PROPERTY" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdffdo.h   251 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POOL_TYPE" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdffdo.h   254 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POOL_TYPE" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdffdo.h   328 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POOL_TYPE" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdffdo.h   348 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PINTERFACE" is undefined    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdffdo.h   463 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PINTERFACE" is undefined    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdffdo.h   482 
Error (active)  E0079   expected a type specifier   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdffileobject.h    137 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdffileobject.h    139 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdffileobject.h    147 
Error (active)  E0079   expected a type specifier   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfinterrupt.h 583 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfinterrupt.h 585 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfinterrupt.h 593 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfio.h    282 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfio.h    298 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfio.h    314 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfio.h    316 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfio.h    334 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfio.h    336 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "ACCESS_MASK" is undefined   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfiotarget.h  303 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "ACCESS_MASK" is undefined   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfiotarget.h  323 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DEVICE_REGISTRY_PROPERTY" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfiotarget.h  621 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DEVICE_REGISTRY_PROPERTY" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfiotarget.h  639 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DEVICE_REGISTRY_PROPERTY" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfiotarget.h  666 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POOL_TYPE" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfiotarget.h  669 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DEVICE_REGISTRY_PROPERTY" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfiotarget.h  684 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POOL_TYPE" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfiotarget.h  687 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PINTERFACE" is undefined    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfiotarget.h  713 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PINTERFACE" is undefined    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfiotarget.h  732 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfiotarget.h  751 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfiotarget.h  761 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfiotarget.h  776 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfiotarget.h  786 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfiotarget.h  801 
Error (active)  E0090   function returning function is not allowed  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfiotarget.h  811 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PMDL" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    135 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POOL_TYPE" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    162 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    167 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POOL_TYPE" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    184 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    189 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    216 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    232 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    253 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    263 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    286 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    300 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    320 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    325 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    336 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    341 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    361 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    366 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    377 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    382 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    404 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POOL_TYPE" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    407 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    426 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POOL_TYPE" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfmemory.h    429 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "SYSTEM_POWER_STATE" is undefined    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfpdo.h   115 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PINTERFACE" is undefined    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfqueryinterface.h    63  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PINTERFACE" is undefined    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfqueryinterface.h    132 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "ACCESS_MASK" is undefined   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfregistry.h  73  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "ACCESS_MASK" is undefined   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfregistry.h  90  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "ACCESS_MASK" is undefined   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfregistry.h  116 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "ACCESS_MASK" is undefined   KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfregistry.h  137 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POOL_TYPE" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfregistry.h  323 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "POOL_TYPE" is undefined KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfregistry.h  343 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PIRP" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   379 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PIRP" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   513 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PIRP" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   528 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PIO_STACK_LOCATION" is undefined    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   636 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PIO_STACK_LOCATION" is undefined    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   646 
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1169    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1173    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1184    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1188    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1208    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1212    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1223    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1227    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PMDL" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1247    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PMDL" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1258    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PMDL" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1278    
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PMDL" is undefined  KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1289    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1309    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1313    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1324    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1328    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1348    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1352    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1363    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1367    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1468    
Error (active)  E0757   variable "size_t" is not a type name    KMDF Driver2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\wdf\kmdf\1.15\wdfrequest.h   1483
```

Comment: Please post errors as (searchable) text, not as image.

Comment: @WernerHenze Have edited the post

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656856/cant-get-visual-studio-c-include-file-excpt-h-to-get-installed

Comment: @WernerHenze
Have tried replacing include value to - ``` $(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath); ```

This had a bit of positive effect removing like 50 errors. Errors - https://pastebin.com/yuvMNX6D (Stack overflow has character limit, so I can't put it there :D

KDMF framework includes are added aswell

Comment: 147 errors are a lot better than 200+. But it does not fix the issue

Comment: Correct, but your original question is solved. Now you have another question (which you only ask in the comments, not in the question itself).